# How to rebuild my Font Book database

Tags: font, font-book

I was having trouble with my font cache in Photoshop, so per [Adobe's instructions](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-fonts-photoshop.html) I reset the font cache with:

```
sudo atsutil databases –remove
```

Now, while most applications will show my fonts, Font Book comes up completely empty:

[image: empty fontbook database]

Is there something I need to do in order to restore my Font Book database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting my computer fixed it.

Comment: Oye, not the answer I was expecting :D

Comment: @GoodSp33d Yeah, "have you tried turning it off and on again?" never feels like a satisfying solution, but sometimes it's the easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that behavior in several computers at the office where the font
book shows empty and i haven't rebuilt the font book. My only solution has
been restarting or shutting down. it fixes it, but comes back after a while.
according with APple the problem is caused by an installed app. They asked 
me to monitors apps that I open to isolate offender. For me that is hard to keep track. it hapens in OS 10.13.X and 10.14.6
Jul-29-2019

Comment: Hi, welcome to Apple.SE! If you feel that the problem is persistent, Please ask a new question and link it there if you wish to. you might want to take the [tour]. Have a good time here :)